# How to set the default open path for a Gtk.FileChooserWidget?

Tags: python, gtk

If I set the current folder via the method `Gtk.FileChooserWidget.set_current_folder()`, the first time I open the file chooser, it opens on the location used as argument for `set_current_folder()`

But, if I select a file, the I re-open the file-chooser, it opens on the "most_recent_used_files".

I'd like it opens on the last selected file's folder path.

How to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: What if you use set_current_folder every time a file is opened?

Comment: It doesn't work. From this point of view this widget has a really strange behavior. Maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> Old versions of the file chooser's documentation suggested using gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder() in various situations, with the intention of letting the application suggest a reasonable default folder. This is no longer considered to be a good policy, as now the file chooser is able to make good suggestions on its own. In general, you should only cause the file chooser to show a specific folder when it is appropriate to use gtk_file_chooser_set_filename() - i.e. when you are doing a File/Save As command and you already have a file saved somewhere.

You may or may not like the reasoning for this behavior. If you're curious about how it came about, see [File chooser recent-files](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2012-November/msg00040.html) in the mailing list and [Help the user choose a place to put a new file](https://live.gnome.org/DocumentCentricGnome/Help%20the%20user%20choose%20a%20place%20to%20put%20a%20new%20file) on the GNOME wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the current folder each time works for me, but it is a little tricky. I'm using Gtk 3.14 and Python 2.7.

You have to get the filename before resetting the directory, or it's lost, and the current directory may be None, so you have to check for that.

This code is tested on Debian jessie and Windows 7.

```
import os.path as osp

from gi.repository import Gtk

class FileDialog(Gtk.FileChooserDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        Gtk.FileChooserDialog.__init__(self, title, parent)
        self.add_button(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL)
        self.add_button(Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK)

        self.set_current_folder(osp.abspath('.'))

    def __call__(self):
        resp = self.run()
        self.hide()

        fname = self.get_filename()

        d = self.get_current_folder()
        if d:
            self.set_current_folder(d)

        if resp == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            return fname
        else:
            return None

class TheApp(Gtk.Window):
    def on_clicked(self, w, dlg):
        fname = dlg()
        print fname if fname else 'canceled'

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.connect('delete_event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.set_resizable(False)

        dlg = FileDialog(self, 'Your File Dialog, Sir.')
        btn = Gtk.Button.new_with_label('click here')
        btn.connect('clicked', self.on_clicked, dlg)

        self.add(btn)
        btn.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TheApp()
    app.show()
    Gtk.main()
```